# Magento 2 How to display custom product attributes on product page

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute

I have some attributes that I want to go above the "Add to Cart" button. How can I achieve this?

I followed this tutorial but that didn't work for me -> http://www.dckap.com/blog/display-custom-attribute-value-product-viewlist-page-magento-2/

I am using Magento version 2.1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create attr.phtml file and call all your attributes inside that file.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attr.phtml

add your **attribute code**

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getAttributeCode(), 'attribute_code'); ?>
```

Inside your xml file

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="attr" template="product/view/attr.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

after that move your **attr** block where ever you want.

for example,

```
<move element="attr" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
```

let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. It doesn't work for me... I did exactly what you said. Also, why is there `$block->getProduct()->getShippingDelivery(), 'shipping_delivery')` is that the attribute? I have created a attribute called bottle_size and added it to attribute set called `liquid`, now I need to bring this attribute in the product view.

Comment: You have to call your attribute there... what ever your attribute code

Comment: Could you guide me through it? Been looking for some tutorials but can't find anything :/

Comment: what are your attribute codes?

Comment: I created a new product attribute with code `bottle_size`

Comment: `<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getBottleSize(), 'bottle_size'); ?>`.. please assign your attribute to product and add some value in it

Comment: I have done, the product has this attribute. It is required. Also, it's still not working... Does it matter if I use custom theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69220/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-bare-feet).